# Регулярное выражение, пропускающее логины, состоящие только из определённых символов, PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь написать регулярное выражение на PHP, чтобы пропускало **только** логины, состоящие из букв русского и латинского алфавита, цифр, символов `_-*#!~.` и пробела. Запутался с русскими символами `[а-я]`, а также с пробелом (использовал модификатор `x`)
Вот моё регулярное выражение:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[а-яa-z0-9_-]+$/ix', $login))
   $errors[] = 'Недопустимые символы в имени';
```

Тут, конечно, не все разрешённые символы. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: А почему бы просто не перечислить все допустимые символы, включая пробельные?

    $login = "Vova_#! .Putin~";
    if (!preg_match('/^[\s\*\#!\~\.а-яa-z0-9_-]+$/i', $login)) { 
        echo 'Недопустимые символы в имени';
    }

Comment: Спасибо, но думаю еще модификатор "u" нужен

Comment: Не помешает

Comment: Только для русских символов с учётом регистра можно использовать такую комбинацию.
[а-яА-ЯёЁ]. Ё указывать обязательно. Так как не везде он поддерживается.

Answer (score 1):

*Дополненный ответ из комментариев:*

```
$login = "Vova_#! .Putin~";
if (!preg_match('/^[\s*\#!\~\.А-Яа-яЁёA-Za-z0-9_-]+$/i', $login)) {
  echo 'Недопустимые символы в имени';
}
```